# Error with citations in apa7 with apacite

Tags: bibtex, apacite, apa7

I'm getting a bunch of errors on running PDFlatex for the second time after bibtex, this is the first error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\hyper@@link ->\let \Hy@reserved@a
\relax \@ifnextchar [{\hyper@link@ }{\hyp...
l.17 \citeA{foo}
blah blah blah blah. Stuff goes here.
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I'm pretty sure this is entirely caused by updating my file to use apa7 rather than apa6, but if possible I'd like to get it working with apa7.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[stu, apacite]{apa7}

\title{Title}
\shorttitle{Other title}
\author{My name}
\authorsaffiliations{School, College}
\course{Course name}
\professor{Dr. So and So}
\duedate{November 15, 2020}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{A section}
\citeA{foo} blah blah blah blah. Stuff goes here. 

\section{A different section}
More writing and stuff \cite{bar}. 

\bibliography{testb}
\end{document}
```

Bib for MWE:

```
@book{foo,
  title={A book title},
  author={Doe, John Bob},
  year={2034},
  publisher={A company}
}

@misc{bar,
  title={Here's a website},
  author={Smith, Jane},
  url={https://www.google.ca}
}
```

Comment: A suggestion that's more of a quick (but hopefully not particularly dirty...) fix than a complete solution: Add `natbibapa` to the list of document class options -- i.e., write `\documentclass[stu, apacite, natbibapa]{apa7}` -- and use `\citet` and `\citep` instead of `\citeA`, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Mico for the suggestion and welcome! I ended up, with substantial effort, fully switching over to `biblatex` instead, since it's the only one that is updated to APA7.